# Expressing inverse beta regularized in terms of Riemann/Siegel theta

Tags: special-functions, inverse-function, elliptic-functions, abelian-varieties, theta-functions

I am new to the [**Riemann/Siegel Theta function**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannThetaFunction.html), but it represents many special cases of [**Inverse Beta Regularized** $\text I^{-1}_s(a,b)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseBetaRegularized/). The Riemann theta function can represent any Abelian function, the inverse of any Abelian integral, with the [following series expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/SiegelTheta3/). If

$$y=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{k=0}^d a_kt^k}}$$ then, its inverse function is a ratio of [homogenous polynomials](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=homogeneous+polynomial) of $$\Theta(\Omega;s)=\Theta\left(\left(\begin{matrix}m_{1,1}&…&m_{1,r}\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\m_{r,1}&…&m_{r,r}\end{matrix}\right);s_1,…,s_r\right)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z^r}e^{i\pi(\Omega n^2+2ns)}$$ where $\sum\limits_{n\in\Bbb Z^r}=\sum\limits_{n_1=-\infty}^\infty\cdots\sum\limits_{n_r=-\infty}^\infty$, $a_n$ is a polynomial coefficient, and the dot product is assumed. The inverse beta regularized function is defined by:

$$\text B(a,b)y=\int_0^x t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} dt\implies x=\text I^{-1}_y(a,b);a,b>0,0\le y\le 1$$

Particularly with the [Incomplete Beta function $\text B_z(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=incomplete+beta+function):

$$y=\int_0^x\frac1{\sqrt{\left(ax^n+x^m\right)^c}}dx=\frac{\left(-\frac1a\right)^\frac{cn-2}{2(m-n)}}{a^\frac c2(m-n)}\text B_{-\frac{x^{m-n}}a}\left(\frac{cn-2}{2(n-m)},1-\frac c2\right)\implies x=\sqrt[m-n]{-a\operatorname I^{-1}_\frac{a^\frac c2(m-n)y}{\left(-\frac1a\right)^\frac{cn-2}{2(m-n)}\text B\left(\frac{cn-2}{2(n-m)},1-\frac c2\right)} \left(\frac{cn-2}{2(n-m)},1-\frac c2\right)}$$

with $0\le \frac{a^\frac c2(m-n)y}{\left(-\frac1a\right)^\frac{cn-2}{2(m-n)}\text B\left(\frac{cn-2}{2(n-m)},1-\frac c2\right)}\le1,\frac{cn-2}{2(n-m)}>0,c<2$ becoming an Abelian function if $m,n\in\Bbb N,c=0,1,c\to2$

However, there should be more cases where inverse beta regularized is an Abelian function. Note that the Riemann theta function is in Mathematica as [SiegelTheta](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=siegeltheta) and as [RiemannTheta](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=RiemannTheta) in Maple. Hopefully, we can now extend the $\text I^{-1}_x(a,b)$ function’s domain since $\Theta(\Omega;s)$ can have complex arguments.

What is inverse beta regularized in terms of Riemann theta?